# NodeJS: How to set Mongoose response globally?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this situation where I need to set mongoose response (e.g. dynamic site name) globally across router. I tried this and it works but I think it's not the best way to do it. May I know what will be the best way to achieve it?

My current code:

```
SomeSchema.findOne({}, function(err, callback) {
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Home'
        });
    });

    router.get('/page1', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('page1', {
            title: 'Page 1'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How is this setting some object globally?  This is just defining a couple routes.  I don't understand what problem you are trying to solve?  If you want us to comment on the viability of some code you have, you have to show us that actual code, not a dumbed down version that doesn't actually do anything related to the problem at hand.

Comment: hi, what i mean is I have my site name saved to mongodb. I wanna repeat the site name to all of the routes. Is this the best way of doing it? or there are better way?

Comment: Well, you don't show grabbing a site name from anywhere and you don't show what you're trying to do with it.  We could guess, but we need to KNOW what both of those are in order to make a suggestion.  Please show us your actual code that illlustrates what you are actually doing.  We don't work very well on guesses or theoretical questions.  We work really well with actual code and an actual problem description.

Comment: Does the site name vary from one request to another or is it fixed when the server is started?  If it varies, what info is used to determine which site name it will be?  How many total site names are there (I'm trying to figure out if caching or pre-loading is appropriate here).  In general, you don't want to be an extra DB lookup for every single route if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to use a middleware. Something that will grab the value you need and pass it along to each request.

If you only need to get the value once, just call it when your server starts. Otherwise see below for the middleware approach.

```
route.use(function(req, res, next) {
  //Runs on every request.
  SomeSchema.findOne({}, function(err, callback) {
    req.someValue = callback;
    next();
  });
})

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.someValue); //My value is here
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Home'
  });
});

router.get('/page1', function(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.someValue); //or here
  res.render('page1', {
    title: 'Page 1'
  });
});
```

Comment: Np. :) Don't forget to accept the answer as the solution. I'd really appreciate it. :)